# How do i implement a locustfile where each locust takes unique value from csv files for it's task?

Tags: locust

```
    enter code here
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task


class ExampleTask(TaskSet):
    csvfile = open('failed.csv', 'r')
    data = csvfile.readlines()
    bakdata = list(data)

    @task
    def fun(self):
        try:
            value = self.data.pop().split(',')
            print('------This is the value {}'.format(value[0]))
        except IndexError:
            self.data = list(self.bakdata)



class ExampleUser(HttpLocust):
    host = 'https://www.google.com'
    task_set = ExampleTask
```

Following my csv file:

516,True,success
517,True,success
518,True,success
519,True,success
520,True,success
521,True,success
522,True,success
523,True,success
524,True,success
525,True,success
526,True,success
527,True,success
528,True,success
529,True,success
530,True,success
531,True,success
532,True,success
533,True,success
534,True,success
535,True,success
536,True,success
537,True,success
538,True,success
539,True,success
540,True,success
541,True,success
542,True,success
543,True,success
544,True,success
545,True,success
546,True,success
547,True,success
548,True,success
549,True,success
550,True,success
551,True,success
552,True,success
553,True,success
554,True,success
555,True,success
556,True,success
557,True,success
558,True,success
559,True,success

Here after csv file end , locust does not takes unique value, it takes same value for all the users which is simulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think your problem is this line:

```
self.data = list(self.bakdata)
```

This will give each User instance a *different* copy of the list.

It should work if you change it to:

```
ExampleTask.data = list(self.bakdata)
```

Or you can use locust-plugins's CSVReader, see the example here:

https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/csvreader_ex.py